# Figure referencing using \autoref takes the cursor to the caption

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

In Overleaf after importing package `hyperref` like this:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

I am using the `figure` environment adding a label after the caption like this:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{Screenshot 2022-01-04 121837.jpg}
    \caption{A schematic of a simple conventional solar cell. Creation of electron–hole pairs, e− and h+, respectively, is depicted.Reprinted from \emph{Handbook of Photovoltaic Science and Engineering} (Chapter 3 Physics of Solar cells, JL Gray, p.83), by A.Luque and S. Hegedus 2003, Wiley, Copyright © 2003 John Wiley \& Sons, Ltd}
    \label{fig:my_label9}
\end{figure}
```

and then using `\autoref{fig:my_label9}` to hyperlink it.
All works normally except the fact that on clicking the link I am led to the caption and one has to scroll up to look at the figure. It would be nice if we could show the entire figure with the caption on clicking.

On request in a comment, I am attaching a minimalistic code to explain the problem which you could copy and run in Overleaf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref} 
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
The birds appears in figure number \autoref{fig:birds} 
\begin{figure}[h!]

  \includegraphics[scale=1.7]{universe.jpg}
  \caption{The Universe}
  \label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}

\newpage



\begin{figure}[h!]
  \includegraphics[scale=1.7]{birds.jpg}
  \caption{The birds}
  \label{fig:birds}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Click on the hyperlink to understand the problem.

Comment: As always on this site you are much more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is (instead of an image you can use `\rule{5cm}{5cm}`. Perhaps also place the `\autoref` on a different page to make the effect more noticeable.

Comment: added an example code @daleif

Comment: As I mentioned, use something else than your images, we don't have them. You can use the images that come with the `mwe` package see https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mwe or use `\rule{5cm}{5cm}`

Comment: Also note that this has nothing to do with `\autoref`, normal `\ref` uses the same target

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/4023925/1195114

Comment: Check the hypcap option of the caption package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes worked

Answer (score 1):

Additional to the hyperref package, use the caption package as well.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
```

This should fix the problem